# PHP Regular expression to capture code

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to capture code blocks in a similar fashion to wiki tags:

```
{{code:
      code goes here
   }}
```

Example code is shown below,

```
$strings = array('AbCd1zyZ9', 'foo!#$bar');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_alnum($testcase)) {
        echo "It is The string $testcase consists of all letters or digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all letters or digits.\n";
    }
}
```

Essentially I want to capture anything between the `{{..}}`. There are multiple blocks like this embedded in an HTML page.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: When you say you want to capture "anything between the `{{..}}`", do you mean you want to include or exclude the "code:" part?

Comment: What kind of "code" block is this? A programming language? Or something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well to start off, regex is *not* a good way to solve this problem. The right approach is to write a parser that understands language semantics and can tease out the subtleties. Having said that, if you still want a quick and dirty regex based approach that will work 99.99% of the time but has a couple of acknowledged bugs (see end of answer), Here you go:

You can use [`preg_match_all()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php). Here is a proof of concept:

```
$input = "
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{{code:echo 'Hello World';}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>{{code:\$strings = array('AbCd1zyZ9', 'foo!#$bar');
foreach (\$strings as \$testcase) {
    if (ctype_alnum(\$testcase)) {
        echo \"It is The string \$testcase consists of all letters or digits.\\n\";
    } else {
        echo \"The string $testcase does not consist of all letters or digits.\\n\";
    }
}
}}</h1>
    </body>
</html>
";

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/{{code:([^\x00]*?)}}/', $input, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
```

Outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => echo 'Hello World';
    [1] => $strings = array('AbCd1zyZ9', 'foo!#');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_alnum($testcase)) {
        echo "It is The string $testcase consists of all letters or digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string  does not consist of all letters or digits.\n";
    }
}

)
```

Be careful. There are some edge case bugs involving early termination by encountering `}}` within a "code" block:

1. If `}}` appears in a quoted string, the regex matches too early
2. If `}` is the last character of your "code" block and it's immediately followed by `}}`, you'll lose the closing `}` from your code block.

Comment: @Asaph Thanks! Will try it out, how can I use the result to say place it in new ,`<div>`

Comment: Just be careful with this. If the code block contains `}}` *anywhere* it will fail and end early. There's no great way to avoid this besides trying to parse the code (look for uneven numbers of quotes before `}}`, etc.)

Comment: @yannis: I'm not sure what exactly you mean. Perhaps if you post some code, what you are trying to do will become clearer. It won't fit in the comments though so please post a new question for that part. Thanks.

Comment: @Cyclotis04: We don't know what kind of "code" block this is. Don't assume it's a programming language. If this is code _is_ a programming language, then maybe `}}` could validly appear quoted within the "code". But the OP doesn't mention this so I didn't try to handle it.

Comment: @Asaph @Cyclotis04 Unfortunately it does contain code, I edited the post.

Comment: @yannis: I just updated my answer so that it handles multiline code blocks. If something like this is valid: `<div>{{code:$myvar = '}}';}}</div>`, then regex is not the right solution for your problem. As @Cyclotis04 hinted, you're basically looking at a (non-trivial) lexer/parser approach to solve it. Alternatively, since `}}` _rarely_ appears in code in practice, you can use my rough and dirty regex solution to start, and accept that you have this minor bug. Then refactor to a more robust solution later. Remember, shipping is a feature! Compromise is your friend.

Comment: @Asaph Thanks again, not sure if shipping early will be ok for me, but certainly for demo version 1.0 is ok.

Comment: @yes123 - `\x00` matches the ASCII character with value 00, so yes - the null character. This means that `[^\x00]` will match every character that is not null - even new lines - without changing any regex settings. (I don't know if this is good practice, but it's pretty cool and something I hadn't seen before.)

Comment: @Cyclotis04: I learned the `[^\x00]` trick from [Jeffrey Friedl's Mastering Regular Expressions book](http://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Regular-Expressions-Jeffrey-Friedl/dp/0596528124/). It's a well supported trick. I highly recommend the book too.

Answer (score 2):

As I've said in the comments, [Asaph's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6397901/php-regular-expression-to-capture-code/6397916#6397916) is a good solid regex, but breaks down when `}}` is contained within the code block. Hopefully this won't be a problem, but as there is a possibility of it, it would be best make your regex a little more expansive. If we can assume that any `}}` appearing between two single-quotes does not signify the end of the code, as in Asaph's example of `<div>{{code:$myvar = '}}';}}</div>`, we can expand our regex a bit:

`{{code:((?:[^']*?'[^']*?')*?[^']*?)}}`

`[^']*?'` looks for a set of non-`'` characters, followed by a single quote, and `[^']*?'[^']*?'` looks for two of them in succession. This "swallows" strings like `'}}'`. We [lazily](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) look for any number of these strings, then the rest of any non-string code with `[^']*?`, and finally our ending `}}`.

This allows us to match the entire string `{{code:$myvar = '}}';}}` rather than just `{{code:$myvar = '}}`.

There are still problems with this method, however. Escaping a quote within a string, such as in `{{code:$myvar = '\'}}\'';}}` will not work, as we will "swallow" `'\'` first, and end with the `}}` immediately following. It may be possible to determine these escaped single-quotes as well, or to add in support for double-quoted strings, but you need to ask yourself at what point using a code-parser is a better idea.

See the entire Regex in action [here](http://regexr.com?2u1bq). (If it doesn't match anything at first, just click the window.)

---

> how can I use the result to say place
>   it in new ,`<div>`

Use the replace function:

```
preg_replace($expression, "<div>$0</div>", $input)
```

`$0` inserts the entire match, and will place it between a new `<div>` block. Alternatively, if you just want the actual source code, use `$1`, as we captured the source code in a separate capture group.

Again, see the replacement [here](http://regexr.com?2u1bt).

---

I went deeper down the rabbit hole...

`{{code:((?:(?:[^']|\\')*?(?<!\\)'(?:[^']|\\')*?(?<!\\)')*?(?:[^']|\\')*?)}}`

This won't break with escaped single-quotes, and correctly matches `{{code:$myvar = '\'}}\'';}}`.

[Ta-da](http://regexr.com?2u1c9).

Comment: +1 for taking the regex one step further but also recognizing that there are still failing test cases and continuing to work through them with a purely regex based approach is asking for trouble.

Comment: PHP supports a variety of ways to quote strings: [single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), [double quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double), [heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) and [nowdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc). This regex is just the tip of the iceberg...

Comment: @Asaph - It is indeed just the tip of the iceberg. Frankly, I'd almost rather write my own PHP parser than try and write that massive regex. To be honest I mostly did this to see what it would take, knowing regular languages can't really count anything arbitrarily.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. You are right probably the best way is to write a short parser, my guess it will probably also perform faster.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
preg_match_all("/{{(.)*}}/", $text, $match)
```

where `text` is the text that might contain code 
this captures anything between `{{ }}`